# Saving multiple image in a single TIFF file in python

Tags: python, image, append, python-imaging-library, tiff

I have multiple numbers of images I want to save each 22 images in TIFF file. I found that I should first save the images then load them to save in TIFF file. I want to save each `cropped` image until the file felled with 22 images. I am trying for more than 2 weeks to find how I can do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Code**:

```
for i, ci in enumerate(coefficients):
        plt.imshow(ci.reshape(1, -1), extent=[0, 3844, i + 0.5, i +1.5], cmap='inferno', aspect='auto', interpolation='nearest')
        plt.ylim(0.5, len(coeffs)-0.5) 
        plt.yticks(range(1, len(coeffs)), ['cD5', 'cD4', 'cD3', 'cD2', 'cD1'])  

plt.axis('off')
 
plt.savefig(FirstPartPathOutput+SecondPartPathOutput+'/spec_'+isPreictal+'_'+str(nSpectogram+1)+'_'+str(k)+'.png')
for image in filePaths :
        image=Image.open(filePath)
        image.load()
        imageSize = image.size
   # remove alpha channel
        invert_im = image.convert("RGB") 
    # invert image (so that white is 0)
        invert_im = ImageOps.invert(invert_im)
        imageBox = invert_im.getbbox()
        cropped=image.crop(imageBox)
```